# declaring a derived class in an IF for use outside

Tags: c++, class, scope, derived-class, base-class

I have the following code where I want to declare an object inside an IF statement. I understand that just declaring it inside an IF means that it's outside the scope of the rest of the program. So I think I need to use a pointer.
My problem is that the classes that I want the user to choose from are derived from a base class. So I figured I probably need to create a pointer based on this base class... That sound about right?

See below for what I'm try to do, am I in the right ball park?

```
//create a stereo input object
StereoImage SO;
SO.open(File1,File2);

int StereoOption;

if (counter == 0) StereoOption = 1;

//think i need to create a pointer to the base class
SVAlgorithm *ptrSter;

//choose which method to use in stereo processing and set the base class pointer to derrived class
     if (StereoOption == 1) {SVOpenCVBlockMatching DoStereo; cout << "Using option 1" << endl; *ptrSter = DoStereo;}
else if (StereoOption == 2) {SVOpenCVSemiGlobalBlockMatching DoStereo; cout << "Using option 2" << endl; *ptrSter = DoStereo;}
else if (StereoOption == 3) {SVNoMD DoStereo; cout << "Using option 3" << endl; *ptrSter = DoStereo;}
else if (StereoOption == 4) {SVCross DoStereo; cout << "Using option 4" << endl; *ptrSter = DoStereo;}
else if (StereoOption == 5) {SVAdaptDP DoStereo; cout << "Using option 5" << endl; *ptrSter = DoStereo;}

//set create DoStereo from the pointer
SVAlgorithm &DoStereo = *ptrSter;

//output matrix
Mat_<short> DispOut;

//load the disparity method params, compute it and show - works
DoStereo.loadParams();
DoStereo.compute(SO.getRawFrame(0),SO.getRawFrame(1),DispOut);
imshow("Disparity Map", DispOut*255);
```

The following classes are all derived from the class SVAlgorithm...
SVOpenCVBlockMatching,
SVOpenCVSemiGlobalBlockMatching,
SVNoMD, 
SVCross,
SVAdaptDP.

Comment: Your pointer hasn't been initialized, so you shouldn't dereference it. I'd recommend changing it to a smart pointer and allocating memory within the `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your code is wrong. Pointer has absolutely no effect on object lifetime.
So this line `SVAlgorithm &DoStereo = *ptrSter;` gives you Undefined Behavior because you try to dereference the pointer to destroyed object.

Another possible problem is uninitialized `ptrSter` and `StereoOption` variables. Looks like here is possible case when `ptrSter` will not be assigned with proper object and its dereference will lead to UB too.

You need to use dynamic storage with `new` statement and store result in some pointer. It's **highly recommended** to use **smart pointer** instead of raw for this purpose, e.g. `std::auto_ptr` for C++03 or `std::unique_ptr` for C++11.

Example:

```
 std::unique_ptr<SVAlgorithm> ptrSter;

 if (StereoOption == 1) { ptrSter.reset(new SVOpenCVBlockMatching()); }
 else if (StereoOption == 2) { ptrSter.reset(new SVOpenCVSemiGlobalBlockMatching()); }
 else if (StereoOption == 3) { ptrSter.reset(new SVNoMD()); } 
 else if (StereoOption == 4) { ptrSter.reset(new SVCross()); } 
 else if (StereoOption == 5) { ptrSter.reset(new SVAdaptDP()); }

 if(!ptrSter)
 {
    assert(false);
    return;
 }

 SVAlgorithm &DoStereo = *ptrSter;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are starting in the right direction with:

```
SVAlgorithm *ptrSter;
```

But now you need something like a factory to create one of your instances, so you should do something like:

```
SVAlgorithm *ptrSter = SVFactory(StereoOption);
```

where `SVFactory()` encapsulates your if statements like this:

```
SVAlgorithm* SVFactory(int StereoOption){
  if (StereoOption == 1) { return new SVOpenCVBlockMatching(); }
  else if (StereoOption == 2) { return new SVOpenCVSemiGlobalBlockMatching();}
  else if (StereoOption == 3) { return new SVNoMD();}
  else if (StereoOption == 4) { return new SVCross();}
  else if (StereoOption == 5) { return new SVAdaptDP();}
}
```

and later:

```
delete ptrSter;
```

Comment: Not a good idea to use raw pointers in 2012. Well, it wasn't good even in 1992, but now it looks like advice to buy a horse when someone need to ride.